# In Ruby, how to read data placed inside the program/script itself?

Tags: ruby, input, io

In `Perl` there is a `__DATA__` token that allows input to be loaded from the program/script file itself. What is the `Ruby` equivalent?

Comment: There's a good discussion of that [here](http://caiustheory.com/why-i-love-data).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Place the data after the `__END__` token, read it in with `DATA.read` (which returns a `String` object), split the string on newline (`\n`), and iterate over the resultant `Array` with `each` or the like.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

DATA.read.split(/\n/).each_with_index do |l,i|
        puts "line #{i+1}: #{l}"
end

__END__
red
orange
yellow
green
blue
indigo
violet
```

Example run:

```
-bash> ruby -W /tmp/x.rb 
line 1: red
line 2: orange
line 3: yellow
line 4: green
line 5: blue
line 6: indigo
line 7: violet
```